# AS3 Jerky animation on first startup

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I have create AS3 game with many images moving on the screen. When I start my for the first time in browser the animation is jerky(images moves not smoothly). But on the second start(when all resources are in browser cache) everything is perfect.
What is the reason of jerky animation?

Answer (score 0):

It should be because of the fact that not all images are preloaded. What Flash does is that it actually tries to play what's loaded, and sometimes if not everything is done - there are some strange animations.

What you should do is to add a preloader (check google, there are tons for AS3, AS2, timeline, classes, progress bars, etc). It should fix the issue.

Comment: Im using greensock LoaderMax and wait for complete event.